# Debug Tests - Not Executed. Waiting for tests to initialize

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mstest

I am attempting to debug a test, but it is not being executed

> Warning   7/12/2012 9:16:53 AM    Test run 'xxx@YYY 2012-07-12 09:14:52'
>   could not be executed. Timed out waiting for the process that runs
>   tests to initialize.

I however do not have any initializer code at all.

This was working previously, but I just modified Nuget in the solution to allow for Nuget Restore. I am unsure of whether this is the cause or not.

How can I debug through my test again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I restarted my computer and my tests started debugging fine.

Comment: lol! This is the standard fixing process when nothing makes sende: Restart IIS, Restart Machine, Reinstall, Look for another job. Mark your answer as accepted one...

Comment: I am also getting same issue but even I restart problem not solved.individual script is running fine.when I try to run orderedtest I am getting the exception

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that Nuget Restore is the cause. In order to confirm it 100% disable Nuget Restore..

Also check if you have any setup methods in your tests (Check attribute [TestFixtureSetUp]). If so, put a breakpoint on them...

Comment: I have only the one test at the moment (new project) and there are no setup methods. I'd prefer not to disable nuget restore as I wasn't able to manage my packages via source control before I enabled it.

Comment: I mean disable it for 5 minutes and try to run the tests again... just to confirm 100% where is the problem.

Comment: thx for the effort, per my answer, I just restarted my computer and everything started working fine :-/ [eyeroll]